# Highcharts: How can I take X-axis value in tooltip?

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I am using Highcharts to draw a graph. I want the tooltip show the exact values of x-axis (eg. 1930-07-01). I used (this.x) in tooltip formatter and it is showing x-axis 0.

How can i the 1930-07-01 value here in tooltip?

Comment: Don't you need  to provide the categories as an array in the xAxis? `xAxis: { categories: [ 1930-01-07, 1931-01-07, ...] }` p.s. You need to provide some code, preferably a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/).

Comment: I passed the data as series data...
And i got it brother by this.point.name

Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Please show your code.  It is impossible to answer your question without knowing how you created the plot.  For instance, Is your xAxis a `category` or `datetime` axis?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17035303/1043380). Could be a duplicate.

Answer (score 18):

In case when you use formatter and categories you can use `this.key` or `this.x`

http://jsfiddle.net/wxxEu/2/