# How to remove decimal time at tooltip on React Highchart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I have an area chart that show some values and datetime in tooltip like picture below :
[image]

This is the options i used :

```
const getConfig = data => ({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    rangeSelector: {    
        selected: 1
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts',
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1000,
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: "{point.y:.0f}"
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Data',
            data: data,
        },
    ],
});
```

I already tried this [customize highcharts tooltip to show datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033752/customize-highcharts-tooltip-to-show-datetime),
with this code :

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return  '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',
                                  new Date(this.x))
        + ' date, ' + this.y + ' Kg.';
    }
}
```

But still not change the lower tooltip (datetime), it just change the upper tooltip (122 value).

How to remove decimal value at tooltip so the time just like `Sunday, Jul 29, 15:50:14`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [customize highcharts tooltip to show datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033752/customize-highcharts-tooltip-to-show-datetime)

Comment: @Daniel with the link you provide, just change upper tooltip in my case just number `122` not the lower tooltip that show the datetime. Can you show me to change the lower tooltip datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **dateTimeLabelFormats**:

```
tooltip: {
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    millisecond: "%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S"
  }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nbgzkwj3/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats.millisecond