# how to convert timestamp in date format in tooltip of highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Here i used line highcharts in my react project and in my line highchart I display tooltip, in this tooltime I have one date but this date is in timestamp format and I want to display this timestamp in date format in tooltip how it is possible in highcharts tooltip ?

```
 tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b>',
    pointFormat: '{point.x}',  // 1554422400
  },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033752/customize-highcharts-tooltip-to-show-datetime) question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [customize highcharts tooltip to show datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033752/customize-highcharts-tooltip-to-show-datetime)

Comment: @tarzenchugh i tried solutions from that answer but it shows same date(18 jan 1970) if i have different different timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use moment.js npm, dedicated to time and all related formats of date and time

Answer (score 1):

In the `pointFormatter` function you can use Highcharts `dateFormat` method:

```
tooltip: {
    ...,
    pointFormatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b %H:%M:%S', this.x)
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oLt62kbu/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

Comment: Hi @DDD, yes because my timestamps  looks like this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`. Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kLfh42ys/